# How to print PNG or SVG file with full details?

Tags: printing

I usually post coding problems in here, but apparently there is also a tag for printing. So here it goes:

I need to print very details designs for a family business. However, the prints results I'm getting with the **Epson 475L** are not what I'm looking for.

> Which better printer do you recommend for a small Stickers Business?

For example:

I need to print this, and it has a "halo" on the top corner of the hexagon.

But my printer does not recognize this and prints a very flat hexagon.

[image]

My prints from **EPSON 475L**:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The printing tag is for those programming questions that involve printing, not to solicit hardware recommendations for a printer,

Comment: @ReddHerring where is a good place to post this question? *before deleting it.

Comment: You might try [hardwarerecs.se]